# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar bien la matriz?

Tags: java, matriz

estoy intentando mostrar una matriz pero el output me muestra caracteres raros, alguien sabe como hacer para mostrar bien?

```
       double[][] matrix = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
       Matriz array = new Matriz(matrix);
       
       System.out.println(array.toString());
       //output: [matrizA = [[D@26f0a63f, [D@4361bd48, [D@53bd815b]]
```

Asi tengo definida la clase:

```
       private double[][] matrizA;

       public Matriz(double[][] matrizA) {
           super();
           this.matrizA = matrizA;
       }

       public double[][] getMatrizA() {
           return matrizA;
       }

       public void setMatrizA(double[][] matrizA) {
           this.matrizA = matrizA;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "[matrizA = " + Arrays.toString(matrizA) + "]";
       }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En Java, las matrices no anulan toString(), por lo que si intenta imprimir una directamente, obtendrá el className + @ + el hexadecimal de hashCode de la matriz, según lo definido por Object.toString()

Para matrices anidadas puedes usar deepToString

```
public class ClaseMatriz {
    private double[][] matrizA;

        public ClaseMatriz(double[][] MatrizA) {
            super();
            this.matrizA = MatrizA;
        }
        public double[][] getMatrizA() {
            return matrizA;
        }
        public void setMatrizA(double[][] MatrizA) {
            this.matrizA = MatrizA;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "matrizA = " + Arrays.deepToString(matrizA);
        }
   }


public class ImprimeMatriz {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[][] matrix = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        ClaseMatriz array = new ClaseMatriz(matrix);
   
        System.out.println(array.toString());
        //output: [matrizA = [[D@26f0a63f, [D@4361bd48, [D@53bd815b]]
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Esos caracteres "raros" es la dirección en memora donde esta almacenado cada dato de tu array.

Utiliza un bucle for o for each para mostrar cada elemento de tu array individualmente.

bucle for each:

```
for(double[] arr2: array){
    for(double val: arr2){
        System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(val));
    }
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, los bucles con una iteración no sirven para mostrar los valores de los array multidimensionales como el que se pregunta aquí. Al menos creo que deberían de llevar dos bucles for o for each

Comment: @Vanessa estas en lo correcto, ya lo edite para que este conforme a la pregunta, gracias por la observación.